# How to convert a LinearLayout in an image while keeping the transparent background

Tags: android, image, itext, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout I want transform in an image, but I saw it turning into a bitmap the background loses transparency. I must then turn it into an image png and doing this and imposing a transparent background with alpha equal to zero is only partially transparent. The image is complete trasparent only on paper white, if the paper is colored the image is partially transparent. I used iText for create image.

```
   mLinearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    mLinearLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

     mLinearLayout.layout(0, 0,  642,  400);


    mLinearLayout.buildDrawingCache(true);

    mBitmapLayoutPreview = Bitmap.createBitmap(mLinearLayout.getDrawingCache());
    mLinearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); //lose transparency


    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mBitmapLayoutPreview.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100 , stream);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmapLayoutPreview);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAlpha(0);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapLayoutPreview, 0, 0, paint);
    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray()); //is only partially transparent
```

I saw that partial transparency is caused by a colorspace = 3 I'm myImg. I'm using iText to create pdf files

Comment: If you comment this line "    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapLayoutPreview, 0, 0, paint); " , your linear layout is transparent or already partially transparent ?

Comment: is already partially transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I not utilized Canvas but I set `BackgroundColor Transparent`:

```
    mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mLinearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    mLinearLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));


    mLinearLayout.layout(0, 0,  642,  400);

    mLinearLayout.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Log.i(TAG, "The color of background is: " +mCardLayout.getAlpha());

    mBitmapLayoutPreview = Bitmap.createBitmap(mLinearLayout.getDrawingCache());


    mLinearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
```

`mBitmapLayoutPreview` is my `LinearLayout` with background `Transparent`

Comment: Since how much time you'r developing android apps?

Comment: Ok Cool. Nice to heard !